# [magento]: emails are not being sent

Tags: php, email, magento, magento-1.9

well, I know there are thousands Q/A on this topic, but none of them seem to answer my question. What I have done so far is that I have configured magento to send emails on port 25 and added the mail server IP. 
After a lot of struggles I found out that magento is sending emails using mail() function, and I checked with this snippet whether it is enabled in my host or not?

```
 <?php 
if(function_exists('mail')) {   echo 'mail() is enabled'; }    
    else {  echo 'mail() is not enabled'; }
```

and the output is that the "mail() is not enabled", so what I did was to ask my host to turn this function on for me, but they were saying it is not turned on for security reasons.

So, How can I set up Magento to use a separate mail server to send its emails through.

What should I do?

Thanks,

Comment: use SMTP way for this

Comment: @TamilSelvan can you elaborate on this? what do you mean by SMTP  way? where can I config it?

Comment: use a 3rd party mail server

Comment: see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11438/how-to-setup-external-smtp-emailing-on-a-local-magento

Comment: I have no experience in using a 3rd party mail server, Could you give me some clues?

Answer (score 1):

We have some other ways to set up smtp for magento, the default settings only accept the basic set up. You can check magento set up tutorial here [Magento SMTP Email Setup](http://magento2x.com/magento-smtp-email-setup/)

Thanks

Comment: Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Hi @Vinod, Thanks for the answer. I followed the tutorial and changed the code in Template.phtml. Now, how can I test whether the email is gonna be sent is there any sample templates? or sth? do I need Cron jobs to be running

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.9 sends mails through the cron job. make sure that is set up correctly!

https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-configure-a-cron-job.html